# Android Studio - Unable to run app on device minSdk(API 25) > device Sdk(API 19)

Tags: android

I have just set up Android Studio and am trying to compile my first project. The project gets compiled but when the 'Choose Device' menu opens the device and state is shown as [OFFLINE] and compatible gives message Android error message Android error 'No, minSdk(API 19) > deviceSdk(API 25)' What does this mean? How can I solve it?

Comment: If the minSDK is 25 and the emulator is 19, **you can't run it on that emulator**

Comment: Your question title does not match the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means what it says. Your device has an SDK less than the one code you be compiled. It won't run there.

Make a new AVD for the SDK you want to use

Comment: My code runs  over AVD virtual device but the problem when my physical cell phone it was connected, thanks

Comment: Okay, then buy a new phone or downgrade your code SDK